# issues coming while upgrading spring boot 3.0.0 with apache camel 3.15.0 , routes are not getting started automatically

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, apache-camel-3, camel-routes

I have upgraded my Spring Boot application to version 3.0.0. However, after the upgrade, I encountered an issue where my Camel routes are not starting automatically. I have attempted to resolve this problem by upgrading the Camel version to 3.18.0, but that did not resolve the issue. Subsequently, I downgraded the Camel version back to 3.11.0, which was the version I was previously using, but the problem still persists.

I am seeking a comprehensive solution to this problem.